# Scraping Google maps by Selenium (Privacy policy)

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want use Selenium to accept Privacy policy with scraped links and then wait when the link will update with geographical coordinates and copy this geographical coordinates to json file

```
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)



driver.get("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/embed?src=vrep2g00lfipsi470hfm1o787o@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/Warsaw")
time.sleep(1)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)

elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rb-ni')))
events = []

elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rb-ni')))
for element in elements:
    try:
        event_title = element.text
        element.click()  # Kliknij na element rb-ni
        time.sleep(1) 

        try:
            mapa_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'menu-link') and contains(@href, 'maps.google.com')]")
            mapa_url = mapa_link.get_attribute("href")
            driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0]);", mapa_url)
            time.sleep(5)
            # Przełącz się do nowo otwartej karty
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            privacy_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 Nc7WLe')))
            
            privacy_button.click() 
            time.sleep(5)
            time.sleep(5)
            
            
            # Zamknij kartę Google Maps
            driver.close()
            
            # Przełącz się z powrotem do karty kalendarza
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        
        except:
            latitude = 'N/A'
            longitude = 'N/A'
    except:
        continue
```

Please write which class i need to find to and click to accept Privacy policy

Comment: Google has a well-defined API to access calendar data.  You don't have to resort to scraping hackery.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Wait until the privacy button is visible
privacy_button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'VfPpkd-LgbsSe')]")))


# Click the privacy button
privacy_button.click()
```

This works.